# What is the best way to show a table in a view using PlayFramework 1.5.*?

Tags: html, model-view-controller, playframework

I'm doing a play framework 1.5.* project, and I need to display some tables, that I get from a mysql database, in a view. I need to display more than one table and the way I'm currently doing it (see below) seems to complicated, and that is just for one table. Is there a better way?

```
public static void listEntities() {

        Item i = new Item();

        List<String> headers = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<Integer> id = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<String> item = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<Integer> quantity = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> range = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        headers.add("Id");
        headers.add("Item Name");
        headers.add("Quantity");

        try {
            ResultSet rs = i.getTableData();
            rs.first();

            do {
                id.add(rs.getInt(1));
                item.add(rs.getString(2));
                quantity.add(rs.getInt(3));

            } while (rs.next());

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        for(int k=0; k < id.size(); k++){
            range.add(k);
        }

        render(headers, id, item, quantity, range);
    }
```

---

```
<table style="width:100%">
 
  <tr>
    %{
      for(h in headers ) { 
    }%
    <th>${h}</th>
    %{
      }
    }%
  </tr>
  
    %{
      for(i in range) { 

    }%
  <tr>
    <td>${id.get(i)}</td>
    <td>${item.get(i)}</td>
    <td>${quantity.get(i)}</td>
  </tr>
    %{
            }
    }%
  </tr>
</table>
```